# Selenium Javascript: how to check aria-label parameter?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I want to check if my checkbox is unchecked, the only parameter that changes is aria-label.

Is it possible to check that parameter with javascript on Sélenium ?

```
<svg class="1-MuiSvgIcon-root-778 1-makeStyles-root-875" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="img" aria-label="CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon"><path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

aria-label is just another [dom element attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes), and since is present in the dom, you could get it with [getAttribute](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/getAttribute/):

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
var driverPath = require('chromedriver').path;
var By = webdriver.By;
var Key = webdriver.Key;
var until = webdriver.until;

async function start() {

  var service = new chrome.ServiceBuilder(driverPath).build();
  chrome.setDefaultService(service);

  var driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
  .build();

  await driver.get('http://localhost:9000');
  const svgElements = await driver.findElements(By.className("1-MuiSvgIcon-root-778 1-makeStyles-root-875"));
  var firstSvg = await svgElements[0];
  console.log(firstSvg);
  console.log("aria-label value = "+await firstSvg.getAttribute('aria-hidden'))
  await driver.quit();

}

start();
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To validate if the [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) is checked/unchecked you can extract the value of the *`aria-label`* attribute to probe further as follows:

- Using *css*:

  ```
  console.log(await driver.findElement(By.css("svg.1-MuiSvgIcon-root-778")).getAttribute('aria-label'));
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  console.log(await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg' and contains(@class, '1-MuiSvgIcon-root-778')]")).getAttribute('aria-label'));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all

Thanks to your help, I manage to find my aria-label parameter.
Since the await and console.log don't work for me (invalid), I modify a bit and now it works !

Here what I do:

```
var test = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg' and contains(@class, '1-MuiSvgIcon-root-778 1-makeStyles-root-875')]")).getAttribute("aria-label");
    System.out.println(test);
```

Result => CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon

Thanks again !